# Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string' - Typescript and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this coding:

```
        this.arrayTemp = [];
          interface tempFull {
             num: number;
             name: string;
          }
          for (const key in group) {
              let temp = {} as tempFull;
             temp.num = parseInt(group[key].length / this.item);
             temp.name = group[key][0];
             if (temp.num >= 1){
               this.arrayTemp.push(temp);
             }
          }
```

The object `Group` is this:

```
{
red:[
 "red",
 "red",
 "red",
],
blue:[
 "blue",
 "blue",
 "blue",
 "blue",
],
}
```

And `this.item` could be any number

The issue tha I have if:

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

    46              temp.num = parseInt(group[key].length / parseInt(this.item));
```

Any help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `parseInt` is `(value: string) => number`.  That is, `parseInt` is a function that converts strings into numbers ... sometimes.  However, you are passing in the result of calling the division operator on a pair of numbers, `group[key].length / parseInt(this.item)`.  A number is not a string.  Remove your wrapping `parseInt` and replace it with a call to `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`, or even just remove the outer call completely if you're fine with a floating point result.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `parseInt` and replace it with `Number` like :

`Number(group[key].length / this.item)`

The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer. In your case, you have integer as argument of `parseInt` that's why its giving error.

For more info on [parseInt() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) and [Number() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameter of parseInt is already a number. If you want to turn it to integer, just do

```js
Math.round(group[key].length / this.item)`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use parseInt() function, please convert parameter as string

```
temp.num = parseInt('' + group[key].length / parseInt(this.item));
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `parseInt` with numbers

You can do:

```
interface TempFull {
  num: number;
  name: string;
}

const arrayTemp: TempFull[] = [];
const group: Record<string, string[]> = {
  red: ['red', 'red', 'red'],
  blue: ['blue', 'blue', 'blue', 'blue'],
};

Object.values(group).forEach(arr => {
  const num = arr.length / this.item; // <-- It's a number
  const name = arr[0];
  if (num >= 1) {
    arrayTemp.push({ num, name });
  }
});
```